# Automating kernel configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, makefile, kernel, config

I have to build custom kernels often enough, that it would make sense for me to have a tool which would take some a short list of approx. 50-100 configuration options and apply them over the default stock config file.

Now, I surely could just take a fresh kernel config (call make nconfig -> save the file without any changes done). Then change the corresponding options and compile the thing. But, the nconfig/menuconfig UIs perform some dependencies - automatically setting the values of depending/relative options. So, my question is:

**(How) can I easily tap into the dependency resolving mechanism?** What I'd ideally like to get is the following: taking a fresh .config file. applying a single change. do *something* to change the values of related configuration options, if there are any to be cahnged.

Thanks in advance!